# Plot latitude longitude with drop wrong data in rows

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

Hello I need help or clue with my data frame.
I have 319k rows with two columns named 'Latitude' adn 'Longtitude', by reason of checking I grouped and coutned the rows: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IqCka.png , https://i.stack.imgur.com/gg9v0.png

I need make scatter plot, but unfortunetely I'm very very new in python, and I don't know how I can find correct long and lat data in rows without empty records or wrong data like -1.0000 (screenshot). Lat and long for Boston (MA) are 42... And -72...

I think my code to plotting is good, but i cant correctly filtered my data to make it:

for seaborn `sns.stripplot(x='Latitude', y='Longtitude', data=MojaBaza)`-> for now, I've got:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/RL1t1.png

for matplotlib `plt.scatter(x=MojaBaza['Longtitude'], y=MojaBaza['Latitude'])` -> and for this instruction, I've got "'value' must be an instance of str or bytes, not a float"

Sorry if my question is stupid, but I really don't know, how handle it.
Greetings

Comment: Are you sure you don't have any data missing? This may be a cause.

Comment: I and my thesis supervisor got it. Problem was in location data (latitude and longitude) was in string type. We changed it to float, and we got what we want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was the type of data.

The solution is:

```
MojaBaza['Latitude']=MojaBaza['Latitude'].astype('float')
MojaBaza['Longitude']=MojaBaza['Longitude'].astype('float')
```

In the next step:

```
Filtr1 = MojaBaza['Latitude'] > 40

Filtr2 = MojaBaza['Longitude'] < -70

Lokacja = MojaBaza[Filtr1 & Filtr2]
```

and we got it:
[image]